# Show all results from database where mm/dd/yy date is "today" or greater

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using HTML input type="date" to allow users to input appointment dates.

Now I want to query the database and show all appointments that are "today" and in the future.
Not dates that have already passed.

Here is my SQL Script

```
$today = date('d-m-Y');
$sql = "SELECT * 
          FROM `client1` 
          WHERE `client` = '$customer'  
             AND DATEDIFF('$today', `date`) >= 0 
          ORDER BY `id` DESC";
```

Can someone guide me as to how I can achieve this?
I have seen several directions online but I want to have the sorting done at the moment of query.

Comment: You shouldn't have saved those dates as strings. Now your job is tougher.

Comment: At least y/m/d is sortable as strings (as long as month and day is padded with zero if <10), so "where 'date' >= '$today'" might work.

Comment: @JohnConde I found the issue. my date() had the wrong format and I had to switch the operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue!

My `date()` format was incorrect because HTML input type="date" inserts `YYYY-MM-DD` into the database =/

```
$today = date('d-m-Y');
```

should be

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
```

My operator `>=` should have been `<=` to show today and future dates.

Thanks everyone for the help. I should have tried fixing it for 5 more minutes before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using PHP to compare dates in the database? I assume its a date field so you can use MySQL to do it for you:

```
SELECT * 
   FROM `client1` 
   WHERE `client` = '$customer'  
       AND DATEDIFF(date_format(now(), '%Y/%m/%d'), `date`) >= 0 
   ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the responses have specified sargable predicates. If you perform an operation on a column in the `where` clause, there is no discernible stopping point.

```
where ... some_function( some_field ) = some_constant_value ...
```

Even if `some_field` is indexed, a complete table scan must be performed because there is no way to know if the output of the operation is also ordered.

From my understanding the `date` column is in a sortable form -- either a date field or a string in lexically sortable format 'yyyy-mm-dd'. That being the case, don't do any operation on it.

```
where ... some_field >= now() ...
```

Thus the system can use the result of `now()` as a target value to find exactly where in the index to start looking. It knows it can ignore all the rows with indexed values "down" from the target value. It has to look only at rows with indexed values at or "up" from the target value. That is, it performs an index seek to the correct starting point and proceeds from there. This could mean totally bypassing many, many rows.

Or, to put it bluntly, ditch the `datediff` and do a direct comparison.